# When am I sure Android Service starts?

Tags: android, android-service

I am starting service by `startService(Intent)` in `onCreate` method in `Activity`. When can I `sendBroadcast` to Service (service registered some `BroadcastReciever`) and be sure Service run completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can start sending broadcasts straight away. The broadcastreceiver will only start to receive once its registered. You could implement broadcastreceivers in both the service and activity and start by sending a message to the service and wait for a response before you start the full sending. Or you could use intents!